# django shell_plus : autoreload not working

Tags: django, ipython

I am using python 3.7 and have intalled IPython

I am using ipython shell in django like

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

and then

```
[1]: %load_ext autoreload
[2]: %autoreload 2
```

and then i am doing

```
[1]: from boiler.tasks import add
[2]: add(1,2)
"testing"
```

`change add function`

```
def add(x,y):
    print("testing2")
```

and then i am doing

```
[1]: from boiler.tasks import add
[2]: add(1,2)
"testing"
```

so here i found its not updating

Comment: exit from shell_plus and  launch again after changing add function to reflect the changes...

Comment: will be in middle of something

Comment: inplace of load_ext autoreload use %load_ext autoreload and inplace of autoreload 2
 use %autoreload 2. That worked for me.  Check the documentation : https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not working for me too. One way you can achieve this is by using execfile.

```
exec(open("./filename").read())
```

Comment: `import execfile` no module found

Comment: No need to import, Just execute it.

Comment: `NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined`

Comment: That was for python2. I have made an update. Please check now.

Comment: you mean in my case `exec(open('absoultepath/boiler/tasks.py).read())`. I did but the `add` function changes not reflected after doing this

Comment: Okay, I think it should work. For me that execfile in python2 works. I think it deprecated. I have updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: you mean after `exec` the add function get reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Inplace of

```
load_ext autoreload
```

use

```
%load_ext autoreload
```

and inplace of

```
autoreload 2
```

use

```
%autoreload 2
```

That worked for me. Check the documentation : [Check the Documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html)

[image: Check this out]

Comment: i used the same

Comment: In the question you have mentioned without '%' sign. Please update the question if you are using with %

Answer (score 0):

If you are using celery, which it looks like you might be doing, shell_plus will not hot reload functions that have been decorated with celery task decorators.  I'm not sure why that is, but we've noticed this same limitation oursevles.

Comment: Yes, i am checking function with celery task, then i will check other functions, thaks for the hint, wasted lot of time on this